# Merge the excels from a folder to one excel into multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a code/macro to merge different excel files at one folder location (may not be open) into a excel with multiple sheets having same name as the individual excel names
Thanks

Comment: This is a very common request that has been addressed in nearly every possible iteration already on this site.  I would recommend searching around.  If you find something that is not exactly what you want, you need to include the code you have, what specifically about it is not correct, and what attempts have been made to address the issue.  SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find these macros by searching this same problem. There are about 4 different ones. No two came from the same source. When coding, if you can't come up with the answer on your own it becomes a puzzle game with Google.

```
Sub GetSheets()
Dim temp As String
Dim name As String
Dim filename As String
Dim sheetName As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim upper As Long
Dim myArray() As String

temp = Range("A2").Value
Path = StripFilename(temp)

On Error Resume Next
upper = UBound(myArray)
On Error GoTo 0

counter = 0
filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Do While filename <> ""
    On Error Resume Next
    upper = UBound(myArray)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ReDim Preserve myArray(upper + 1)

    Workbooks.Open filename:=Path & filename, ReadOnly:=True
    sheetName = FileNameNoExt(filename)
    myArray(counter) = sheetName

    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      If sheet.name = "Report" Then
          If Len(myArray(counter)) <= 31 Then
            sheet.name = myArray(counter)
          Else
            sheet.name = Left(myArray(counter), 31)
          End If
          sheet.copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
      End If

    Next sheet

   Workbooks(filename).Close False

   filename = Dir()
   counter = counter + 1
 Loop

 Sheets(1).Select
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
End Sub
```

This function gets the files from a specified file path from cell A2. Then it checks the name of the sheet and compares it to "Report", if the sheet name is "Report" then it copies (this was adapted for the situation I needed. you can remove the 'if' statement and just copy). This is the main sub you run. The following functions are just helper functions used by the main to help get file names with no extensions/paths/etc.

```
`Function StripFilename(sPathFile As String) As String

'given a full path and file, strip the filename off the end and return the path
    Dim filesystem As New FileSystemObject
    StripFilename = filesystem.GetParentFolderName(sPathFile) & "\"

End Function

Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
' Returns the rightmost characters of a string upto but not including the rightmost '\'

    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function

Function FileNameNoExt(strPath As String) As String
    Dim strTemp As String
    strTemp = Mid$(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\") + 1)
    FileNameNoExt = Left$(strTemp, InStrRev(strTemp, ".") - 1)
End Function`
```